# Homomorphisms of Lie Groups

Tags: differential-topology

$SO(3)$ denotes the *special orthogonal group*, which is the (open) subset of $O(3)$ on which the determinant is one.

I have shown that every element of $SO(3)$ fixes a line in $\mathbb{R}$ pointwise and then $SO(3)$ is connected.

Also, suppose $f:G\rightarrow H$ is a smooth map of Lie groups such that $f(g_1g_2) = f(g_1)f(g_2)$ for all $g_1, g_2 \in G$ (this is called a Lie group homomorphism). Then I proved that the derivative $df_g$ has constant rank.

I am stuck at the question: Consider the map $f: S^3 \rightarrow SO(3)$ given by $r \in S^3$ maps to the element $f(r) \in SO(3)$ such that $f(r)(q) = rqr^{-1}$ for $q \in \mathbb{R}$, thought of as a purely imaginary quaternion. Show that this is a Lie group homomorphism, and compute $df_1: TS^3_1 \rightarrow TSO(3)_I$.

I am given then *Hint:* $TS^3_1$ is identified with the purely imaginary quaternions as it sits in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $TSO(3)_I$ is identified with the skew-symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices as it sits in $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$.

More specifically, I am confused with these questions:

1, What is the explicit form of $r^{-1}$? I used $r^*/\|r\|^2$, where $r^* = a -bi-cj-dk$. But then it becomes cumbersome during the computation.

2, I am aware of that quaternions are not really 4-dim since it is bounded on the unit sphere. So should it be 9 x 3 matrix other than 4 x 9? Also, f is 9 dimensional, so df should be 9 columns, right?

Comment: Comment: $S^3$ represents *unit* quaternions, so $\|r\|=1$, right? I have no idea where all these $9$'s are coming from. ou do not want to be doing these computations in local coordinates, but both $S^3$ and $SO(3)$ are $3$-dimensional manifolds, anyhow.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi ted, the 9's are the nine entries of $TSO(3)$ - in fact I think they should be 3 entries, since $TSO(3)$ are skew symmetric....